# How to pipe the stdout to a file if the current command is already being piped through gzip

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, pipe

So I have this command I need to run then disown:

```
innobackupex-1.5.1 --user=root --password=**** --stream=tar ./ | gzip - > /data/myfile.tar.gz
```

How do I pipe any output to a file?

adding another >> to the end of this command only appends the gzip data.

to be more specific;
innobackupex has progress output - I want this output appended/piped to a file (not just errors).
The normal way of doing this (by adding >>) will not work in this case due to the gzip already piping

Comment: Really ambiguous question Tom.  Just look at your answers.

Answer (score 4):

`innobackupex` doesn't output its progress on `stdout`, otherwise, it would end up in the `tar.gz` file. Most likely, it outputs it to stderr (a quick glance at the script seems to confirm it), so what you need to do is redirect its stderr:

```
innobackupex ... 2>> progress.log | gzip > file.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to capture STDERR from innobackupex?  Your question isn't very clear.

```
innobackupex-1.5.1 --user=root --password=**** --stream=tar ./ 2> /path/to/file | gzip - > ...
```

Comment: STDOUT from innobackupex piped to a file would be since there is a lot of information - especially progress information -

Comment: Ummm ... that doesn't explain what you want to achieve, either.  You're already handling STDOUT  from innobackupex using the pipe into gzip.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by means of running these commands in a subshell

```
( innobackupex-1.5.1 --user=root --password=**** --stream=tar ./ \
   | gzip - >  /data/myfile.tar.gz ) 2> errors
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you mean, you want to pipe the output to both gzip for compression and a regular file, here's an example of `tee` usage:

```
ls -a ~ | tee ls.txt - | grep "^\."
```

This will print all of the "hidden" dot files in your home directory (because of grep), but the entire output of `ls -a` will be in ls.txt.

See `man tee` for a complete explanation.

2) If you mean you want to include the standard error stream in the standard output stream, append `2>&1` to the command.